# Ubuntu 17.10.1 Not Installing on Virtualbox

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, oracle

Hello to all Linux users! I'm having a very difficult time installing Ubuntu 16.04.3 and 17 (both ISO)
The version I'm trying to install at the moment on my VirtualBox is 17.10.1. What happens is whenever i get it to boot to the Install or Try Ubuntu w/o Installing, I click on the Install option and takes me through all the settings i want to opt for is fine, the problem is when it is actually installing the packages. I let it run for 2 hours and still nothing

Thanks people. By the way "Try Ubuntu W/o Installing" Option works fine. I just want to be able to have some saved files so i can be able to shell script.

Comment: What is the host operating system (running in the computer)? Which version of VirtualBox are you running? What size is your virtual disk?

Comment: Add amount of memory assigned and number of CPUs

Comment: Windows 8, Version 5.2.6 r120293 (Qt5.6.2), the iso is 1.4Gb. I've tinkered with the (2)core , (3gb)ram, and (30gb)storage capacity, Im still falling flat.